# Pandas XLSXwriter: open XLSX file and save with format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

**Problem description**

[`ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for pandas is capable of storing xlsx files with defined formats, but is it possible to *capture the formats* and keep them to the datafile as well? So;

1. open an xlsx file and capture the number/time/date/.. formats; then
2. save the file with exactly the same formats, for example number, dates and time formats.

Examples of storing with number formats can be found [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_column_formats.html), and storing with date and time formats can be found [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_datetime.html).

**MWE**

1 - open an xlsx file and capture formats

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# capture the number/time/date/.. formats here?
df = pandas.read_excel("sourcefile.xlsx")
```

2 - save xlsx file with the same formats

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("targetfile.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Set the captured formats here

writer.save()
```